# Is there any annotation like "Work in progress", "todo", "implementation not finished" or "draft" in java/kotlin?

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, annotations

I'm looking for annotation with similar functionality as @Deprecated witch tells other developers that the code is a draft and contains a robust implementations or there is a work in progress and me (or someone else) finish it soon.
The problem occurs because I'm working in very huge team. And sometime we have to commit only raw implementation (not optimized).

So is there any similar annotation which will be somehow handled by IDE (like IntelliJ or Android Studio)?

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/opt-in-requirements.htm

Comment: You can use `@RequiresOptIn` and `@OptIn`. More about it [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/opt-in-requirements.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware that such an annotation exists in the core library. But you could write your own:

```
public @interface Draft {
}
```

Comment: ya, I know but how to force to ide to handle them?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'IDE to handle'. What should the IDE do?

Comment: e.g. shows in other part of code some note that it's a draft. Like Deprecated is handled by strikethrough.